# htaccess mod rewrite need to rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

To redirect `mydomain.ru` to `mydomain.ru/rus`.

If I write:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mydomain\.ru/rus/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.ru/rus/$1 [R=301,L]
```

When I have an endless redirect. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Host will in both cases be mydomain.ru, that's why you will get the endless redirecting
Try this instead:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/rus/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ rus/$1
```

This will check wether or not you are currently browsing something in the rus folder, and if not, redirect you to that subfolder